# How to break the loop in the main function, using keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

how to break loop with keypress ("Y"):

I want to stop function by pressing key "Y", not **CTRL+C**.

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            if (num % 2) == 0:
                print("Even number")
            elif (num % 2) != 0:
                print("Odd number")
        except (ValueError, Exception):
            print("Inappropriate number")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the input in a variable, check if it's Y and then convert it to an int

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            val = input("Enter a number: ")
            if val == 'Y':
              break

            num = int(val)
            if (num % 2) == 0:
                print("Even number")
            elif (num % 2) != 0:
                print("Odd number")
        except (ValueError, Exception):
            print("Inappropriate number")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: One could also use a [signal handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#) for this purpose, namely a user-defined signal like SIGUSR1, where you would set a variable in the handler and check it later in the _while loop_.

Comment: @kali Signals have nothing to do with this problem.